# when executing Powershell Script from Ruby "Can't convert true into String" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, powershell

I am trying to execute a powershell script from Ruby, I have entered the below command:

```
scriptPath =  system('powershell \"C:\\Scripts\\DB_Setup.ps1\"')
```

The ruby Script is handling exceptions when an error is raised to stop the script as below command:

```
rescue => ex
  message = "\nscript on server '#{`hostname`.strip()}' terminated unexpectedly:\n\nMessage: '#{ex.message}"
raise ex
```

Output Error:
script on server 'TestDB1' terminated unexpectedly:
Message: 'can't convert true into String'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to tell without seeing your script.  Looks like your .ps1 script echos out a Boolean object, and Ruby isn't liking it.  Either silence it, or change it to a string:

```
PS C:\> (1 -eq 1).gettype().name
Boolean
PS C:\> (1 -eq 1).tostring().gettype().name
String
PS C:\>
```

Comment: PowerShell would output »True« in that case, though. I'd find it unlikely that Ruby would convert »True« to lowercase, just for its error message.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick reply, I know that it is pretty easy to run a powershell script from ruby as mentioned in this link http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DNRTVScreencastPowershellIsStillShiny.aspx
, but for some reason I kept getting the same error message even though running a very basic powershell script such as below:

```
function Main()
{
  Write-Host "Servername"
}

. Main
```

Plus on the otherside I tried your above solution.

This is very strange issue, after spending so much time on it I did a workaround to run a bat file from ruby kicking off the powershell script, I know this is not a good practice...